# Android sdk not installing

Tags: java, android, sdk, windows-10

I accidentally deleted Android folder in windows AppData/Local folder. Now I am trying to reinstall it through Android studio's package manager but getting error that there is not enough space. I have more than 400GB free space on the disk. How can I install Android again. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should redownload android studio and allow it to automatically install all required sdk components.

Comment: I have android studio downloaded tried reinstalling it but it is not installing Android sdk. The project is also giving error that no sdk found.